# After a memory upgrade of my Cisco WAAS, why is the connection limit still the same, how can I raise it?

Tags: cisco, waas, memory

We use Cisco WAAS appliances for WAN optimization. With increasing traffic, we noticed that the connection limit was frequently reached. In case of our WAVE-574-K9 with 3 GB RAM, there was a limit of 750 connections.

So we decided to upgrade the RAM, since it's said that this will raise the supported number of connections. No problem to get 3rd party memory, since it's an OEM version of a Hewlett-Packard Proliant server.

After I installed 2x2 GB RAM modules, removing one 1 GB module. However, the connection limit stays the same, as I can see in the WAAS central manager monitoring. How can I get more connections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, ensure that the memory modules work and are recognized:

```
#show memory
Total memory             :    5986852 KB
```

After adding RAM, it's necessary to repartition the disks for resetting the space allocation for the data redundancy elimination:

```
disk delete-data-partitions
```

A `reload` forces rebuilding of the partitions. You can watch the progress using

```
show disks details
```

If this is finished, check your connections:

```
#show tfo detail

   Policy Engine Config Item            Value
   -------------------------            -----
   State                                Registered
   Default Action                       Use Policy
   Connection Limit                     1300
   Effective Limit                      1290
   Keepalive timeout                    3.0 seconds
```

I could see, the connection limit has been doubled now after doubling the memory.